# How do I make text contain actual pressings of the TAB-key?

Tags: windows, firefox, keyboard

I'm working on entering data to a website and one block where I'd have to enter data contains a bunch of boxes and I'd have to enter a newline-separated block of text to subsequent boxes. If I simply copy and paste the data, it simply pastes the whole block of text to a single box, which doesn't display it properly so I'd need to paste it so that it fills out all the boxes instead. Now, I don't have admin access and I can't change anything about the site architecture, but what I can change is my input.

Does anyone have any tips on how I could go about altering the text (from Notepad ++ to Firefox in this case) to the replace the newlines by actual, physical pressings of the tab key (as opposed to the tab-space created by pressing said key in a text editor) so that my browser would parse the text to the different boxes automatically when copy-pasting? Or is there some other means of going about this in a sane manner? Doing this a few thousand times manually feels mighty unnecessary when clicking a key twice should be able to accomplish the same, but I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: there is a program called 'type it in' by wavget. and you can say something like a{tab}b

Comment: Cheers! And it has a 30 day trial too, perfect!

Comment: Nice question but it has nothing to do with Notepad++ so I suggest you remove the unrelated things from the question, just making it clear that you want newline separated text lines auto-placed into different input boxes in a browser. The title is a bit unclear also.